# CognitiveServices POST response: data.hasOwnProperty failing for all but root of nested JSON object using raw JS

Tags: javascript, json

I am posting a request to Azure Cognitive Services (sentiment API) which returns a nested JSON object as follows (this is a JSON.stringify object output):

```
{ "error": "{\"documents\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"sentiment\":\"neutral\",\"documentScores\":{\"positive\":0.15,\"neutral\":0.8,\"negative\":0.05},\"sentences\":[{\"sentiment\":\"neutral\",\"sentenceScores\":{\"positive\":0.15,\"neutral\":0.8,\"negative\":0.05},\"offset\":0,\"length\":4}]}],\"errors\":[],\"modelVersion\":\"2019-10-01\"}" }
```

I have spent 3 days trying and failing to access the nested key:values using javascript, so I can write individual keys/values to HTML elements using raw JS.

I've validated the JSON is correct using jsonlint.com

I've tried removing '/' characters by both re-parsing, and .replace, but the "cleaned" JSON still does not provide access to documents[]

I've used the following function, found on SO, to validate the stringify string against the object:

```
     //Get nested object structure with key names
         function traverse_it(data){
            for(var prop in data){
                if(typeof data[prop]=='object'){
                    // object
                    traverse_it(data[prop[i]]);
                }else{
                    // something else
                    alert('The value of '+prop+' is '+data[prop]+'.');
                }
            }
        }
        traverse_it(data);
```

I've used `data.hasOwnProperty` to test for property existence - the only property that returns TRUE is "error":

//Check for individual properties

```
          if(data.hasOwnProperty("error")){
              console.log(data.error);
            alert('yippidydippity')
         }else{
            alert('nope')
         }
```

Attempts to access `error.documents`, `error.documents[0].id`, or locate the documents array all fail. I've searched through similar problems on SO but have not found anything that works.

How can I access the individual keys and values of this object using JS? Many thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
let obj = { "error": "{\"documents\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"sentiment\":\"neutral\",\"documentScores\":{\"positive\":0.15,\"neutral\":0.8,\"negative\":0.05},\"sentences\":[{\"sentiment\":\"neutral\",\"sentenceScores\":{\"positive\":0.15,\"neutral\":0.8,\"negative\":0.05},\"offset\":0,\"length\":4}]}],\"errors\":[],\"modelVersion\":\"2019-10-01\"}" }

let obj2 = JSON.parse(obj.error)

//now you can access id from object

console.log(obj2.documents[0].id)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Mohit. I have previously tried to re-parse, and tried again with your code as follows:

                text = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2)
                let obj = text
                let obj2 = JSON.parse(obj.error)
                console.log(obj2.documents[0].id)

The parse only works for JSON.parse(obj) - when executing JSON.parse.job.error the following is returned:

app.js:80 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: why do you stringify data?

Comment: Oh wow - you're amazing, that has fixed it. I thought the object needed to be converted to string to re-parse, but doing exactly as you described to original object has unlocked it! You have saved me so much time! Thanks!!!